# Как декодировать текст из Азбуки Морзе?

Tags: java

Есть код, который текст или цифры переводит в Азбуку Морзе, нужен код, который будет делать наоборот(декодировать), не могу разобраться, как лучше сделать. Вот код кодировки, на его основе нужно сделать обратный код.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] english = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
            'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
            'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
            ',', '.', '?' };

    String[] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
            ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
            "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
            "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.",
            "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" This is an English to Morse Code Translator.  ");
    System.out.println(" Please enter what you would like translate ");
    System.out.println("             into Morse Code. ");
    System.out.println(" ============================================ ");

   String userInput = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();


    char[] chars = userInput.toCharArray();

    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < english.length; j++){

            if (english[j] == chars[i]){
                str = str + morse[j] + " ";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daeris, вот так можно сделать:

```
public class test {
static final char[] english = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                                'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
                                ',', '.', '?' };

static final String[] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
                                ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
                                "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
                                "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----",
                                "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };


public static String engToMorse(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < english.length; j++){
            if (english[j] == chars[i]){
                str = str + morse[j] + " ";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static String MorseToEng(String s) {
    String[] letters = s.split(" ");
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < morse.length; j++){
            if (morse[j].equals(letters[i])){
                str = str + english[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    System.out.println(engToMorse("What is your name?"));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(engToMorse("My name is Daeris"));
    System.out.println(MorseToEng("-- -.-- -. .- -- . .. ... -.. .- . .-. .. ..."));
}
}
```

Рекомендую метод main не использовать для вычислений. Выносите все в методы. Это хороший стиль программирования.

Comment: В ответе не обязательно добавлять обращение к автору вопроса: 1 - и так понятно, что вы обращаетесь к нему, 2 - он и так получит оповещение, что на вопрос ответили, 3 - обращение в ответе не преобразовывается в ссылку, 4 - пользователь может сменить ник, может быть удален (ник пользователя в вопросе заменится на ник вида `user1234`, а обращение в ответе ни изменится), тогда обращение будет непонятно к кому. Я когда-то ставил обращения, через несколько лет пришлось их удалять.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Еще маленький вопрос - как правильно прикрутить в методы ввод информации пользователя?

Comment: Боюсь,здесь в комментариях я не смогу выложить полноценный код. Задайте отдельный вопрос с меткой java. Я с удовольствием отвечу.